# Accessing images uploaded to Azure blob from bot framework

Tags: botframework, azure-blob-storage, azure-bot-service

I have uploaded a `.png` image from Azure bot using AttachmentPrompt and image is stored at `http://localhost:52225/v3/attachments/7e46c370-2f09-11eb-8de3-8bfedba8e1e0/views/original`. Image is not being stored as a `.png`, but without any extension. How to access this file ? I need to pass this file to OCR Read endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are about to call [this API](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005) with the image that stored on your local side, you can just upload binary data of this image to `OCR READ API` with HTTP request header: Content-Type: `application/octet-stream`.
Just like below :

[image]

Let me know if you need more assistance.